# Proving that if a vector belongs to a null space then a multiple of it also belongs to a similar nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Given that $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices with $B=P^{-1} A P$ how can I prove that

if a vector $\vec{x}$ $\in$ Null(B), then P $\vec{x}$ $\in$ Null (A)

Answer (score 0):

Given that $0 = Bx = P^{-1} AP x = 0$. This implies $AP x = 0$ which by definition means $Px \in N(A)$.